# LMA Packages Latest Version Merge Field Not Populating

Tags: massemailmessage, merge-field, lma

I'm trying to create an email template that uses the `Lead.Name` merge field and `sfLma__Package__c.sfLma__Latest_Version__c` merge field.

When I "Send Test and Verify Merge Fields" - choosing a Lead recipient record and the Package related record, those fields populate just fine.

When I attempt to mass email (or directly email) that same lead from the Leads page, only the Lead.Name field is populated.

Am I doing something wrong?